# Wired Xbox 360 USB controller not picked up inside Mac M1 on XEMU

Tags: macos, usb, games

[image]

I have a wired Xbox 360 controller with USB end as shown in the picture above. I am trying to get this recognized inside XEMU for playing an Xbox game.

It does not get detected at all on my Apple M1 Mac Mini (2020 M1 mini; 16GB RAM; Ventura 13.4)

Can someone kindly tell me how to make XEMU detect this controller?

Comment: Let's look at this step by step: Does your Mac recognize the controller (aka can you play Mac games with it)?

Comment: @nohillside there s no light on the controller at all, it blinks when i connect to the other windows machine

Comment: Are you sure a wired Xbox controller even works on Macs?

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/409420/successor-for-360controller-to-support-wired-xbox-one-controller

Comment: Getting it detected will be the first thing you need to ensure before moving on. 
 When you plug in your device, issue the Terminal command `system_profiler SPUSBDataType > ~/Desktop/USB_Report.txt`.  Go through that text file that is created on your Desktop and see if you can find the device.  If it's not there, it's not being detected.  If you're not sure, upload it to iCloud/OneDrive/Dropbox/etc. and share the link.  You can also paste it to [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/)